# Is there a possible way to allow the `webview-html` to communicate with the local notification?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, notifications

I am  creating IPhone application which has a `webview` this `webview` views a local `HTML` page and this HTML page a has JqueryMobile Calender. I want to use this calender to schedule a notification for the date comes from this calendar.

Is there a possible way to allow the `webview-html` to communicate with the local notification ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use  tags or jQuery to create a conduit between the webview's content and the app. You can use this UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  if(![[request URL] isEqual:[NSURL URLWithString:eventNotificationName]]){
     // do something
  }
}
```

Trigger a page load with a location that has whatever string you want, and check for it in that delegate method to trigger some application-side event.